# php mysql query resource null ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, null, resources

I have a connection to mysql database which works well for the core directory of my syte
mysite.com
but doesn't work for mysite.com/adm

Both directories have similar code and i searched for mistakea ALOT

it gives me error

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given
>   in /var/***/adm/index.php on line 9

the code on line 9 looks like this:

> $result = mysql_query($query, $link);

and the variable $link works well for the other files

Comment: suggest you to switch from mysql_* to mysqli_*

Comment: Maybe your connection to the database is failing...do a var_dump($link); and post the output

Comment: it should be for  `$link` is not connected to the database.

Comment: I understand that but it is conneted when i am in other directories. I set connection in file connect.php and everywhere i use require'connect.php' and it works well everywhere but there.

var_dump($link); goes like this: resource(3) of type (mysql link)

Comment: Is this a legacy application? `mysql_query` shouldn't be used in new code because it's been deprecated, is dangerous if used incorrectly, and is being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) has a number of recommendations as to how to keep your application up-to-date.

Comment: no its new and im a begginer, so thanks i will read those links that you provided, thanks, but so it would be faster beacause i dont want to change all my coding, what would be the solution for this one particular peroblem?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I forgot to pass the connection to function and nothing worked. Passed it as argument and everything is ok now. Still changed from mysql to mysqli functions but it wasnt the issue. Thanks.